# how to install .msi to remote virtual machine's using wix installer without using c#

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to install .msi(wix installer) to remote virtual machine's without c# code.
If i run .msi, msi will ask input like for ip-addresses, username and password for to install software on multiple remote machine's.

**What i don't want - write power-shell script and power-shell will copy .msi to remote and install .msi to remote machine.**

Comment: If you don't want to write code to perform this administrative task, _maybe_ [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) is the place for this question. But then again, administrators do write code to perform administrative tasks.

Comment: writing code is ok but should inside .msi not external powershell script

Comment: I'd recommend editing the MSI, checking the property table to see if there's properties for the attributes you've mentioned (ip-addresses, username and password). As an aside, how are you planning on executing the MSI on the multiple VMs?

Comment: Perhaps you have two questions here. On the install on one machine front, would settings properties on the msiexec.exe command-line work for you. Go `msiexec/?`

Comment: @TomBlodget how to use msiexec/? in wix?

Comment: @SolidSid .msi will accept ip-address,username and password and install remotely.

Comment: @Moglesh To edit the MSI directly, use a tool like InstEd to open it up and add the information to your properties. As TomBlodget states, these properties might be public meaning you can call them via the MSIEXEC command, but it would be worth editing the MSI directly for ease of use. http://www.instedit.com/

Comment: msiexec is the part of Windows Installer (part of Windows) that uses .msi files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/command-line-options

Comment: so i should do remote installation through custom actions and power-shell scripting right. so my powershell will copy msi to remote and then install with msiexec.

Comment: Yeah you could do that but it would be worth checking those properties before putting together the custom actions, it might save you the effort.